# Tastypie: Directing overridden urls depending on request method

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm working with one URL in question, let's call it `/user/{id}/buckets/`

I'd like a GET on `/user/{id}/buckets/` to redirect to `dispatch_list` but a `POST` to redirect to my own view `(process_buckets)` for processing.

I understand that urlconfs don't support any way to check for the request method, so how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply overwrite a resource's dispatch method to do whatever you want

```
class FooResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        # The usual stuff

    def dispatch(self, request_type, request, **kwargs):
        # Do whatever
```